# None of the packages included exists

Tags: servlets

i have made a sample servlet program and on compiling it is giving error. Error says that none of my included packages exists. following is both my servlet class and errors.

**classpath** :

> .;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\lib\jsp-api;

**Path**

> %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\bin

**Servlet class (Ch1Servlet.java)**

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.io.*;

public class Ch1Servlet extends HttpServlet
{
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        out.prtinln( "<html> " + "<body> " + 
                    "<h1 align = center> HF\'s chapter1 servlet <h1>"
                    + "<br>" +today+ "</body> " + "</html>"
                    ) ;
    }
}
```

**ERROR**

[image: **ERROR**]

Comment: Don't define a CLASSPATH environment variable. Always pass a `-cp` option to javac (and java): `javac -cp D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.37\lib\jsp-api Ch1Servlet.java`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one error : 
i have written -- >

```
import javax.io.*;
```

it should be -- >

```
import java.io.*;
```

and rest of the errors got sorted out after i restarted my system.